# Shrink the Desktop image inside table without changing other images and contents of tables

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

If you can help me I would be really appreciated.
My problem is related to email responsive design. There is an desktop image inside table which I resized according to mobile and other devices, but this image inside nested tables.Thus, whatever I do regarding resizing the image according to mobiles. It doesn't look good on mobile because of the parent table features , what you recommend me to do?

Comment: Please provide your code (at jsFiddle as example) or link to the page you're talking about. It's hard to tell without additional info

Comment: it doesnt allow me to send half of the code in here, it says it is too long. what should I do? It is my first time in this website. should I send u as message?

Comment: You could try to give me url to your website

Comment: <body>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
          <center>
          <table>
             <tr><td><center>
<table class=”row”><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<table class=”twelve columns”></table> 
<table class=”row”> another tables inside in it</table>
<table class=”twelve columns”><tr><td><span id=image switcher><img id=banner-full>desktop image</img></span></td><td class=”expander”></td></tr></table>
And there are other tables like that which has images too.
</center>
 </td></tr></table>
</center>
</td></tr></table>

Comment: it is a responsive email (newsletter), it looks good in regular browser,but the desktop image which doesnt fit into tables in the mobile, some of the part of the image was cut, when I play with width of the image, it fits to mobile look, but this time it affects other images in other tables. I am really stucked, if u give me your email,I will send you the website. I am really stucked.

Comment: let's try, paradoxetion@gmail.com